# Spring Boot Actuator Endpoint Override

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-boot-actuator

I have been prototyping with Spring boot where I added dependency on `spring-boot-starter-actuator` and `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` and named my testing REST endpoint to `/info`. Application ran without any errors however my endpoint couldn't be called and app returned 404 all the time.

After some time I found out that actuator project contains SAME endpoint `/info` and basically overrides my custom RESTful endpoint since I didn't name it.

My question is: Is there any way how I can prevent such behavior in general (meaning bean clashing by mistake)? Or at least get WARN message when this is happening.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: Given the *convention-over-configuration* philosophy for spring boot  it is unlikely to produce a warning. However the information might be made available via info / debug / trace logs at best.

Comment: There is no *bean clash*, the endpoint mappings are not defined as a class, as you have mentioned in your question, with the proper annotations you are creating mappings to certain methods in some controller class. In case of the presence of duplicate endpoints the priority goes to the actuator endpoints since their mappings are created afterwards, there might be another way to force the creation of their mappings first so you can override the native endpoints at all times. But it is much better to utilize what spring-boot offers; usage of the `endpoints.enabled` properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable `/info` actuator endpoint by using the following property;

```
management.endpoint.info.enabled=false
```

Actually all can be disabled, or you can enable only certain ones, if you check the source link I've provided below;

> By default, all endpoints except for shutdown are enabled. If you prefer to specifically “opt-in” endpoint enablement you can use the endpoints.enabled property.

[source](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-customizing-endpoints)

For logging of this behaviour, while deploying you can see the endpoints and corresponding beans, you can deduce from this log I guess. But better not to use same endpoint with actuator while they are enabled.

Comment: I am not looking for this particular case, I am more into general solution. In anyway thanks for hint about disabling this one.

Comment: @Kucera.Jan.CZ You can disable all those actuator endpoints also with the properties, I don't understand what can be more general than that. Did you investigate the source link I've supplied in the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a chance to disable particular classes by `@EnableAutoconfiguration` with a parameter `exclude=` where you can specify classname or whole package by using {} brackets

Example:

- `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MyClassName.class}`
- `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MyClassName.class, MyClassName2.class})`